# How to know if firebase child of child of child is current user uid?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Please help me get uid]

I know there are lot similar questions but nothing works for me. I tried so many ways. Here are my code.
so Basically If the current user uid is equals to child of joined_users I want to show text "Joined"

```
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("joined_users").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(myUid);

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
            holder.tag_room.setText("Joined");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: `.equalTo(myUid)` declares that... so what's the question? These `chatid` & `uid` nodes are useless. I wouldn't bother to answer that, unless you could provide an extraordinary good reason for what you need them.

Answer (score 0):

This code:`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("joined_users")` looks at the node `joind_users` directly under the root of your database. That is not where the data in your screenshot is, which explains why the query finds no matching nodes.

If you want to read the data in your screenshot, you'll need to start with `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/Rooms//51008/joined_users")`.